# Deserialize ISO 8601 date time string to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to use:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>( "2009-02-15T00:00:00Z", new IsoDateTimeConverter() )
```

But it gives me a `FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Needed to embed it with quotes. "\"2009-02-15T00:00:00Z\"". Thanks, rubber duck!

Comment: Dirk, you saved my life!

Comment: lol. doubt it, but glad that I could have been a help anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're parsing a single value, the simplest approach is probably to just use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "o", null);
```

The "o" pattern is the [round-trip pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip), which is designed to be ISO-8601:

> The "O" or "o" standard format specifier corresponds to the "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK" custom format string for DateTime values and to the "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffzzz" custom format string for DateTimeOffset values.

I haven't specified a format provider, as it doesn't matter:

> The pattern for this specifier reflects a defined standard (ISO 8601). Therefore, it is always the same regardless of the culture used or the format provider supplied.

If you need Json.NET to handle this transparently while deserializing other values, it may be a trickier proposition - others may know more.

Additionally, just as a plug, you may wish to consider using my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project, which supports ISO-8601 and integrates with JSON.NET - albeit not in a pre-packaged way just yet.

Comment: How would I use Noda Time to do the ISO-8601 conversion?

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: In Noda Time 1.2, you'd use `OffsetDateTimePattern.GeneralIsoPattern` to parse to an `OffsetDateTime`. Or if it's *always* got a `Z` rather than a different offset, you can use `InstantPattern.GeneralPattern`.